# GA - ecommerce over multiple views

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I have ecommerce tracking setup and working fine, now i want to add some extra views/profiles to the same analytics property, will the ecommerce information also show up for the new view or do i need to do anything to make sure this works???

Comment: As long as ecommerce is also enabled in your new view it should show up.

Comment: I've enabled ecommerce yesterday on the new views but still nothing is showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Wait 24 - 48 hours. If it still doesn't work I will do some testing.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo, its been over 24 hours already so i think something needs to happen before it will work.

Comment: I think it should have worked by now as well.  I just posted it in the G+ community I would like to know the answer as well.  These guys will know: https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346/posts/ctv9Zx7fCVv

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo i've taken a look at that thread but i still have no data showing. I think it could be due to filtering. I have only 2 views on this profile, main and articles. The articles view is filtered to Include only - traffic to the subdirectories - that contain /article. Would this be preventing the transaction data from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that filtering does affect ecommerce transactions and values from appearing on a analytics view. The best method is to use segments to show transactions on certain areas/categories of your website.